# Block router to set up PPPOE

Tags: router, dd-wrt, blocking, pppoe

Can ISP block WIFI router from setting up PPPOE connection?

My ISP filtered clients by MAC. I cloned my MAC to WIFI router and everything was fine. 
Today my ISP started to block all WIFI routers. My Dlink DIR-300 with DD-WRT can not establish PPPOE connection anymore. 
PPPOE works fine on all PCs I tried. It seems there is no MAC filtering anymore and ISP uses another method to find WIFI routers.

Answer (score 0):

Change TTL in Windows OS.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
DefaultTTL DWORD dectimal 129 or Hex 81
```

Restart OS.

TTL129.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"DefaultTTL"=dword:00000081
```

Restart OS.

TTL-Restore.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"DefaultTTL"=-
```

Restart OS.

Restore default delete DefaultTTL.

Set TTL 128 in Dlink DIR-300 if possible.

```
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -o `get_wanface` -j TTL --ttl-set 128
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i vlan1 -j TTL --ttl-set 129
```

[DD-WRT wiki Iptables command](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables#Modifying_the_TTL)

Change ISP ...